# What's git bash and why it is mingw64 after opening it?

Tags: git

I have done researching but still confused. 
Is `git bash` windows' git console or something? 
I opened it and it is `mingw64` on the title bar. 
Is `mingw64` similar to `cygwin` or `putty` or what? 
Please explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`mingw64`](http://mingw-w64.org) is the windows port of the GCC C compiler.

[`git`](https://github.com/git/git) is a VCS written in C.

[`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) is a shell, a command line interpreter similar to `cmd` also written in C. You can use it to run git commands or any other programs installed on your computer.

`mingw` was used to compile `git` and `bash`. Seems like nobody cared to give that window a good name, and the compiler just named it after itself.

`cygwin` and `putty` are very different. They also give you some kind of black window and allow you to type things, but `cygwin` pretty much emulates a complete unix environment and `putty` allows you to connect to remote hosts.